# Find sum from 2 tables and write code in php

Tags: sql

This is the query image:
[image: this is the query image]

This result should appear as follows:
[image: this result should appear as follows]

This is my query: `select id, name, total where student.id= marks.sutdent_id`

Comment: How to write php program for this query

Comment: 1. For SQL, you may refer to answer provided by Mureinik . 2. For PHP. You may either use mysqli or PDO in PHP to connect to the db and then use some simple PHP statements to generate the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group on the student id and name and sum the marks:

```sql
SELECT   s.id, s.name, SUM(e.marks) AS total
FROM     student s
JOIN     exam    e ON s.id = e.stud_id
GROUP BY s.id, s.name
```